# Get SessionId in jQuery Post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session

I am doing a jquery $.post('/Home/jQueryRateForumItem',  but when I get to my controller the session id is always different on each post.

I have tried;

```
        string g = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
        string session = base.Session.SessionID;
```

I'm pretty sure The session id shouldn't change but can't for the life of me think how to fix this.

**EDIT**

It's happening when I refresh the Index page as weel so not just on ajax postbacks.  I am using cassini and not IIS though this is the first time I've had issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your code and I couldn't reproduce the behavior you are describing. By default sessions are tracked by cookies so make sure that you've enabled cookies on your browser or it might create a new session on each request.

Also make sure you store a value into the session or the session cookie won't be created. Let's take for example the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = base.Session.SessionID;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

First navigate to the `Home` action, then go to `About` and when you come back to `Home` the session id changes. That's normal as nothing was stored into the session. If you simply set some value `Session["foo"] = "bar";` it will work as the session cookie will be set by the server.

Comment: that was it.  I wasn't storing a value in the seesion beforehand.  I handn't quite gotten to that stage. :)  Thanks